# One-liner for fopen, fprintf, fclose?

Tags: c, linux, printf, fopen, fclose

I'm putting some very temporary debug prints into various userspace programs to figure out what code runs on an embedded Linux device, and I want these prints to write to a file without leaving it open. To make the debug more portable between the various programs, it would be nice to have a one-liner that can open a file, write to it, and close it without having to define a function/macro elsewhere. I could do something like:

```
{ FILE *f = fopen("filename", "a"); if (f) { fprintf(f, "DEBUG MSG\n"); fclose(f); } else printf("File open error!\n"); }
```

which is just removing the whitespace from:

```
{
    FILE *f = fopen("filename", "a");
    if (f) {
        fprintf(f, "DEBUG MSG\n");
        fclose(f);
    }
    else
        printf("File open error!\n");
}
```

But this feels needlessly complex. Is there some more simplified way of doing this? Again, I'm not talking about making it a function, as I'd like it to be copy/pasted between separate programs without defining a function every time. It's just basically a temporary printk equivalent for userspace.

Comment: Usually those one-liners are called functions...

Comment: One-line as in 'in the source code'? Best make it a macro, so you can easily disable it later on.

Comment: Sure: Put the logging stuff into a seperate module, call the "open" function of that module early from `main`, the `close` just before you end your program and the `log` function wherever you want to write to the log file.

Comment: Any particular reason that code in not using something like a function called `debug_printf(int, ...)`?

Comment: Added clarification to the question. I'm not really looking for a "make it a function" solution because I want something simple to paste into multiple programs, similar to using printk's. Just looking for anything I may have missed in my block that could simplify it.

Comment: In the case where `fopen` fails, you should be writing your error message to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick YES! Of course! That is exactly what I was looking for. You can make this into an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce things to one line?  Do you *really* believe your brain can comprehend that many things going on at once?  Or do you endeavor to produce code you can't understand?

Comment: I'm voting to close this, because it's a Code Golf type question. *Here's my really bad idea that works. Can anybody make it shorter?* is a challenge, not an actual problem you're facing. There's an entire site here at [se] for those sorts of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Mark Plotnick, a workaround for Linux systems is:

```
system("echo DEBUG MSG >> filename");
```

It's not pretty but it's quick, copy/pasteable, and easy to use for this situation because it can also write to `/dev/kmsg`:

```
system("echo DEBUG MSG >> /dev/kmsg");
```

which allows it to behave like a printk. Of course, it's not a safe solution and can't be used with any chars that interfere with a bash echo, but for a temporary static debug message it works fine.

Comment: Note: This is an OS specific solution.  The post did not specify the OS and had "runs on an embedded device" which implies there might not even be an underlying OS.

Comment: Good point. I added this to the question. I was hoping for a more general solution (like a library function that I had been unaware of or something) but this one solved the problem for my situation.

Answer (score 5):

---

> `Functions.`

---

Extra chars for my shortest answer.

Answer (score 1):

Potential problem with `fprintf(f, "DEBUG MSG\n");`

I assume `"DEBUG MSG\n"` is some placeholder for the true message.  Should the true message contain a `'%'`, then the function will look for missing arguments.  Use `fputs()` - its can be lighter on the CPU too than `fprintf()`.

```
fputs(debug_message, f);
```

The true message may lack a `'\n'` and then get stuck in buffering just prior to a program crash.  Best to flush when you are done.

```
fputs(debug_message, f);
fflush(f);
```

Pedantic: Debugging is for problem solving.  Too often the message itself is questionable/corrupt.  Consider using protection.  (I do not trust excessive long debug messages).  Of course the more junk in the `fprintf()`, the greater the performance impact of debug logging.

```
if (f) {
  if (debug_message) {
    fprintf(f, "%.99s", debug_message);
    fflush(f);
    fclose(f);
  }
}
```

As mentioned by [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755645/one-liner-for-fopen-fprintf-fclose#comment61091938_36755645), send diagnostic message to `stderr`, rather than `stdout`.

---

Overall, I would use a function call wrapped in a conditional macro rather than embedded code.  YMMV.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
  #define DEBUG_PUTS(level, s)
#else
  #define DEBUG_PUTS(level, s) debug_puts((level), __FILE__, __LINE__, (s))
#endif
```